# REPL for FlowType

Tags: javascript, flowtype, read-eval-print-loop

Is there a Repl for FlowType? The official site [Flow Repl](https://flow.org/try) has a built in error checker. However, it doesn't evaluate your flow code. Is there anything like the [Babel Repl](https://babeljs.io/repl) that allows user to test their flow code for errors and evaluate the code? Ideally something that will `console.log` the results.